# How to make locators generic in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using below piece of code and class to make locators generic using OOO.
Firstly I have webelement.properties

```
LOGIN=id:login_id
PASSWORD=xpath://pwd_xpath
```

I have ObjectConstant file

```
public static final String = LOGIN;
```

I have an interface LocatorsFactory

```
public By getLocator(String locatorelement);
```

I have classes such as IDclass implementing LocatorsFactory

```
@Override
    public By getLocator(String locatorElement) {
        return By.id(locatorElement);
    }
```

I have another LocatorManager Class which loads the properties file

```
Properties p = new Properties();
    public LocatorsFactoryManager (String PropertiesFilePath){
          try {
            p.load(new FileInputStream(PropertiesFilePath));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getElement(String elementName){
        String element = p.getProperty(elementName);
        return element;
    }
    public LocatorsFactory getLocator(String locatorElement){
        String locator = p.getProperty(locatorElement);
        String locatorType = locator.split(":")[0];
        String locatorValue = locator.split(":")[1];
        LocatorsFactory lf = null;
        switch (locatorType.toLowerCase()){
        case "id" : new IDLocatorFactory();
                    break;
        }
```

Where I am stuck is how shall I pass locatorValue to IDClass and make it work and how shall I call in ObjectConstant file as I am creating separate object classes for different pages.

Comment: what is the purpose of `ObjectConstant`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Don't pass around strings as locators and parse out whether they are IDs or XPaths, etc. Just pass around `By` locators and you can avoid all the parsing and extra classes and methods. For example,

```
private By loginLocator = By.id("login_id");
```

With that one easy to read line, you've eliminated the need for 20+ lines of code in your framework.

If you want to follow OOO principles, look into the [page object model](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern). There's lots of documentation on it. You'll want to store locators for a given page inside of a class that represents that page along with the methods the represent user actions.